# What is the correct watch order of Arrowverse in 2017?

Tags: arrowverse, the-flash, arrow, suggested-order, supergirl

I'm trying to keep up with four shows in the Arrowverse: *Supergirl*, *The Flash*, *DC's Legends of Tomorrow*, and *Arrow*. In past years, the air dates of *Supergirl* were a month or so after all the other shows had already started and it was confusing.

In October 2017, *Supergirl* Season 03 Episode 01, *The Flash* Season 04 Episode 01, DC's *Legends of Tomorrow* Season 03 Episode 01, and *Arrow* Season 06 Episode 01 ALL aired the same week, one day after another. So the viewing order obviously follows the air dates.

So I concluded that the correct watch order for 2017, on into 2018 is as follows:

1. *Supergirl*
2. *The Flash*
3. *DC's Legends of Tomorrow*
4. *Arrow*

Then I came upon *Supergirl Crisis on Earth X*, part 1. I watched it, and decided to watch part 2.  So I started watching *The Flash*, Season 04 Episode 08, only to find that it was listed as Part 3?!

I was confused and now I'm trying to find the correct watch order. What other episodes have I watched out of order?  Did they air a 4 part series in the incorrect order?  Something obviously happened, and I guess I just want to know how I can confidently watch these shows in the correct order (beyond crossovers that clearly label the watch order). If I was watching them when they actually aired, it wouldn't matter.  Because if one episode skipped a week, I wouldn't be lost/confused.  But since I don't watch them when they air, I don't really know how to make sure that I'm still watching them in the correct order.

Is there a simple way to make sure I'm still watching these in the correct order?  The only other way I can think is to look up an episode guide for EACH show, and check the air dates/episode numbers to make sure I'm still watching them in the right order.

Comment: There's a really great list answering this exact question on IMDB, found here: http://www.imdb.com/list/ls074499769/ . The author groups episodes of the same show where possible making it easier to binge watch each series.

Answer (score 8):

The *easiest* way to make sure you watch everything in order is to watch them by air date. Even if you don't watch them live or DVR'd, you can just use a Google search for "Flash episodes" or Ärrow episodes" to see their air dates.

However, it's pretty easy this year to binge watch them. So far the only crossover point has been the big four-part crossover, and as far as I know, that's the only planned crossover this season. What threw everything for a loop is that this year's crossover was compressed into *two* days instead of three. Specifically, the *Arrow* episode S06E08, that should have aired on Thursday, November 30th was moved up to air immediately after *Supergirl* S03E08, on November 27. That meant that for exactly one week, *Arrow* aired before *Flash* instead of after.

So, if you want to binge watch the episodes, you need to do this:

- Watch all 4 shows, up through episode 7 of the current season.
- Watch episode 8 of each show in the order the *show's titles* are numbered: *Supergirl* -> *Arrow* -> *Flash* -> *Legends of Tomorrow*
- Resume watching at your leisure.

Comment: I was afraid that the only way would be to just check every episode, BUT it is very relieving to hear that this crossover is the only one planned and that everything should continue as normal after!

Comment: Felicity was in the fifth episode of the Flash this season. As I don't watch Arrow, I don't know if it has any impact on the viewing order. Also, there are many rumors/fan theories that a character from the Flash may move to Legends of Tomorrow.

Comment: No, Felicity's appearance in that episode was just a "cameo", it doesn't have any impact on _Arrow_.

Answer (score 4):

**Crisis on earth-x** was a special case scenario wherein the part 1 and part 2 were **telecasted on the same day** and **it was a two-day event** and so the orders were out of whack for this one...

**Source:** https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Crisis_on_Earth-X

1. Supergirl - November 27, 2017
2. Arrow - November 27, 2017
3. The Flash - November 28, 2017
4. Legends of Tomorrow - November 28, 2017

That also explains why the titlecard was also changed for this crossover event to ensure that it was "almost" standalone in approach.