# Suggested viewing order for complete DC Arrowverse to date?

Tags: arrowverse, suggested-order

I expect to complete the first season of *Arrow* today after purchasing it on BD and would appreciate some tips on where to go next.

I am aware that a similar question has been asked and answered with regards to those seasons first broadcast in 2017 here: [What is the correct watch order of Arrowverse in 2017?](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/84339/what-is-the-correct-watch-order-of-arrowverse-in-2017) but as a total newbie I could real do with some help in lining them all up from start to finish.

My gut is to simply go with the consecutive release dates for all seasons of *Arrow*, *The Flash*, *Supergirl* and *DC's Legends of Tommorow* as advised in the other answer, but as it specifies that 'it's pretty easy **this year** to binge watch them... (with only one) ...planned crossover this season', does this suggest that it may not always be this straightforward?

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/117192/what-is-the-viewing-order-for-cws-dc-shared-universe

Comment: Usually standalone show can be viewed as whole, but you should watch crossovers as broadcasted order to make sense of'em